# Watin not recognising confirmation dialog OK button

Tags: internet-explorer-8, automated-tests, watin

I recently started a new testing job and my predecessor ran an automation suite using watin, which I've had no previous experience with so I'm sorry if I'm not able to give you the relevant information
When I run the suite it (against IE 8.0.7601.17514) seems to get stuck when ever there is a confirmation dialog and the next step is to press ok

```
//Enter invalid data
            var confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
            IE.DialogWatcher.Add(confirmDialog);
            using (new UseDialogOnce(IE.DialogWatcher, confirmDialog))
            {
                //Click to reset data entry
                IE.Page<DataEntryPage>().ResetVoucherButton.ClickNoWait();
                confirmDialog.WaitUntilExists(40000);
                confirmDialog.OKButton.Click();
                WaitForPostBackToComplete.WaitForAsyncPostBackToComplete(IE);
            }
```

It just hangs there and waits for the time out period to pass.

I thought the problem was with my IEStaticInstanceHelper.cs file but it seems to be correct

```
using System.Threading;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace WatiN
{
    public class IEStaticInstanceHelper
    {
        private IE _ie;
        private int _ieThread;
        private string _ieHwnd;

        public IE IE
        {
            get
            {
                var currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
                if (currentThreadId != _ieThread)
                {
                    _ie = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.By("hwnd", _ieHwnd));
                    _ieThread = currentThreadId;
                }
                return _ie;
            }
            set
            {
                _ie = value;
                _ieHwnd = _ie.hWnd.ToString();
                _ieThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
            }
        }

        private int GetCurrentThreadId()
        {
            return Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

I've recently rebuilt my computer (well my sysadmin did) and this wasn't an issue before it was rebuilt, but I can't think what may have changed

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit**

I didn't actually have to change the code, I just had to update my Watin Version as it couldn't handle what ever differences there were between earlier IE 8 dialog boxes and newer ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with IE 9.

I used the following to simulate the shortcut keys on the dialogue

```
 using (browser)
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait("+(%S)");
                    }
```

Send Keys = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

Does this help?

Comment: Hi, I didn't actually have to change the code, I just had to update my Watin Version as it couldn't handle what ever differences there were between earlier IE 8 dialog boxes and newer ones. Thanks though